# Why am I getting AutoMapping Exception

Tags: c#, automapper

I get this exception -

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
>   List`1 -> MyType
>
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] -> MyAssebmly.MyType

where `MyType` is just another POCO with necessary properties.
And my code is -

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AnotherType, MyType>()
            .ConvertUsing<CustomTypeResolver>();
```

where

```
 internal class CustomTypeResolver : AutoMapper.ITypeConverter<AnotherType, 
 MyType>
 {
    //EDIT
    public MyType Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return new MyType { MyList = new List<T> { new T { ... } } };
    }
 }


 internal class MyType
 {
     public List<T> MyList { get; set; }
 }
```

Any one have an Idea what's going wrong.

Comment: I don't understand how the generic type parameter is working. How is `T` defined in the CustomTypeResolver?

Comment: Can you show actual mapping call?

Comment: After doing all of your Automapper setup (`CreateMap`, etc...), are you calling `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid`?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a mapping from `AnotherType` to `MyType` but given that exception, you are trying to convert a `List` to `MyType`. I assume you want to convert each object from the collection and not the whole collection (i.e. the `List` object) so update your code accordingly.